# Water Hardness Test

Tags: water

We have very hard water and we installed both water softener and reverse osmosis filter. When we test water that is only through softener, testing strip says the hardness is about 250 ppm. When test water through both softener and RO filter, the hardness is < 25 ppm. We set water softener to 25 gpg. The testing strip does not say it is testing TDS so I assume the testing strip tests calcium and magnesium. Does it mean our water softener is not working correctly?

Comment: Hi Sophie, I am confused.  If the reading has gone from 250 to 25, then it must be working.  But please post details of test strip and softener and filter.  Maybe even a photo.

Comment: Normally you "set" a water softener to the hardness of the **incoming untreated** water, so it knows when to regenerate itself... So this all seems a bit confused.